# Class inside a Class not recognised issue

Tags: c++, oop, forward-declaration

When I try to compile my following code , I receive an error that Test does not name a type. How is this possible as I seem to have included the header files correctly? Thanks in advance.

```
//Test.h
#include "Test2.h"

class Test
{
    Test2 t2;
};

//Test2.h
#include "Test.h"

class Test2
{
    Test t;
};

//main.cpp
#include "Test.h"

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: The third tag pretty much answers your question (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration).

Comment: Research the internet for "c++ include guards".

Comment: Why would I search the internet for c++ include guards? What has that got to do with this problem? They are removed especially here for simplicity of including less code in the question and showing the main issue.

Comment: @Engineer999: Don't get tetchy -- people here are trying to help you! Removing those include guards has changed your problem from a finite one to an infinite one. Put them back in (after you have worked out why they are essential here).

Comment: I know people are trying to help and thanks. It's just the way it was put. I understand the purpose of include guards and it would cause an infinite problem here without them so I should have left them in. I'm fairly new to C++ so I'm just trying to understand how the compiler works.